# Django rest framework: Get detail view using a field other than primary key integer id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

My Product model has an extra field named "product_id" which is a uuid string. Now I can get the product details based on the primary key id. I want to change this to get the product details using "product_id" field.

My current urls.py

```
url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProductDetailCustom.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
```

Now am calling like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/1460
```

I want this should be like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/04396134-3c90-ea7b-24ba-1fb0db11dbe5
```

views.py

```
class ProductDetailCustom(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCustomSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class ProductCustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields =  ('url', 'id','product_id', 'title', 'description','structure','date_created',)
```

I think I have to include a look field to achive this.

Answer (score 13):

Add `lookup_field` to `product_id`:

```
class ProductDetailCustom(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "product_id"
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCustomSerializer
```

The `lookup_field` would be used by the `get_object` call which would retrieve the model instance. So you can write a custom `get_object` method on your view.

Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview

Comment: What change needs to be done in urls.py ? Actually we need to call string as product_id

Comment: change the regex to make sure it can accept `product_id`. for now it seems to accept only numbers?

Comment: this way?  `url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>[\w\-]+)/$', views.ProductDetailCustom.as_view(), name='product-detail')`